# DIV in HTML dynamically changing but add white space

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have been working on a dynamic question thingee(technical terms) but of course there is always some small hop that you need to overcome.
My issue is that when I select 'show answer' on one of the question panels then the dividers add a massive white space between the rows.
Basically the amount of questions asked are managed by the width of the screen, then via AJAX is gets the questions from `index.php?questions&a={insertwidthofscreen*4}` this is done via javascript and works automatically.

The code that I have is the following, it is called 'math.php' as a temp test:
http://pastebin.com/MjGgSTYh
Everything is generated via the above file and no external connections are made, the database stuff is easy and I will use my old system that keeps a track of what has already been shown.

The idea is that all the DIVS change height when the answer button is clicked, the height is dependent on the answer, the answer could vary from 1 word to a paragraph.

Screen shots of what I mean with the white space.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pHya.png
there is two photos in that, I didn't see the next button for a while.

Cheers,
Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it isn't complete code (and therefore difficult for me to test myself) I'll just spitball this -- your qbox style (and possibly others?) have fixed width -- qbox is 200px. Should that be dynamic? (you also have width listed twice, but same value so it shouldn't matter in this case)

If you want to post more complete code that I can paste into a file myself, I'd be able to troubleshoot much easier.

Update:

I see what is happening now. The whitespace occurs when you click the answers in a particular order -- ie if you go through them left to right top to bottom, there is no extra whitespace, but if you click diagonally like in your screencap, the whitespace is added to allow for the length of the current answer, but doesn't reorder the previous cells to utilize the space.

In order to resolve this, it looks like you'll have to relocate some of the answer boxes when one answer is clicked on... just expanding them in a certain order will cause the issue you're seeing. Another option would be to have an answer pane/frame, on the side or bottom of the page, that shows the answer without expanding the question boxes themselves. I can't picture the algorithm you'd need to auto rearrange the boxes every time one is clicked...

Comment: This is all the code in the PHP file, apart from an alert box that comes up if there is existence of $_REQUEST['dialogue'] but that just gives an explanation to people, apart from the alert the full code is above, I shall double check.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, the only thing that changes would be the height, it could change a lot when the answer button is clicked or it couldn't be much, I cant have a fixed height or the question may be to long and not fit in. The file name is called math.php NOT index.php this is my error and that may be why but you should be able to copy and paste the file, else I have put the file on pastebin http://pastebin.com/MjGgSTYh

Comment: Ok, I've had a look properly at the code above and it isn't complete, Turns out that stack have removed some of it. http://pastebin.com/MjGgSTYh

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML source in the browser, to see what's being rendered by the browser? I don't have access to my php-enabled system at the moment, but can hopefully take a look tonight.

Comment: I've had a look but there are no DIVS or easy to see spaces it is live on http://testa.lhdns.tk/math.php if you want to have a proper look

Comment: It looks fine to me... [image on imgur](http://imgur.com/u2XXNbt).  What browser are you using? I'm on Firefox 31.7 (old, but corporate controlled)

Comment: Just realized I linked the wrong shot -- I clicked on all of the answer buttons, but they formed just fine with no whitespace... It sounds like a browser compatibility issue.

Comment: I am using the latest chrome so perhaps. I will have a go at completing this soon, only really need questions and answers for this now. Manual stuff. Fun, cheers for your help.

Comment: I updated my answer, take a look -- it's not a browser bug, just an artifact of the order in which you exposed answers.